# HTML/CSS dynamic number generator

Tags: html, css

How to generate dynamic numbers as they could be used as 6 digit pin number for logging into a particular page ??

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript for that. Here's an example which will alert it in a default alert box. You'll probably want to do something else with it, but the logic is the same for creating a random 6 digit number:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(100000+Math.floor(Math.random()*900000));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what CSS has got to go with it. You have many options eg. javascript or php.

You need to provide more information but if I understand it correctly PHP would be best as it is server side. Javascript could be a security issue if you using it as a captcha.

You could use

```
<?php echo rand(0, 999999); ?>
```

Comment: Not necessarily PHP. Any server-side language would do.